# Finding the number of $4$-tuples of consisting of digits $1$-$6$ satisfying a certain condition

Tags: probability-or-statistics, pattern-matching, associations, combinatorics, counting

I'm trying to enumerate a sample space for an experiment in which $4$ fair $6$-sided dice are rolled such that exactly $3$ of them are $5$s or $6$s. The way I understand it, the last die must be any number other than $5$ or $6$.

The original problem was to find the probability of this occurring, which I think would be $\dfrac2{81}$, but I'd like to verify this.

I think this can be done easily with the help of `Tuples` and `Counts`, but I'm not sure how to implement `Cases` to pare down the results to only get the outcomes I'm interested in.

```
In[1]:= tuples = Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 4];

In[2]:= Counts /@ tuples

Out[2]= {<|1 -> 4|>, ..., <|6 -> 4|>}
```

The next step would be to somehow get `Cases` to pick out only those tuples for which the counts of `5` and `6` add up to $3$, then find that result's `Length`.

If my conjecture is right, that result would be `32`, so that `32/Length[tuples]` returns `2/81`.

**Workaround:** An alternative approach that occurred to me was to consider $3$-tuples instead for which `Counts` would return either of `<|5 -> 3|>`, `<|5 -> 2, 6 -> 1|>`, `<|5 -> 1, 6 -> 2|>`, or `<|6 -> 3|>`. To recap:

```
In[3]:= tuples3 = Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 3];

In[4]:= counts3 = Counts /@ tuples3;
```

I had thought to use the pattern

```
In[5]:= patt = Alternatives[<|5 -> _|>, <|5 -> _, 6 -> _|>, <|6 -> _, 5 -> _|>, <|6 -> _|>];

In[6]:= Length[Cases[counts3, patt]]

Out[6]= 8
```

and this, if I'm not mistaken, is the expected result. Multiplying by $4$ accounts for the possible faces of the fourth die, giving $32$ out of a total of

```
In[7]:= Length[Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 4]]

Out[7]= 1296
```

possible, and so the probability indeed appears to be $\dfrac{32}{1296}=\dfrac2{81}$.

To summarize, my question(s) would be

> - How can I use `Cases` in a similar way on `tuples` to account for the requirement that the fourth die cannot have a value of `4` or `5`?
> - Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: "the last die must be any number other than 5 or 6" - `Cases[tuples, {Repeated[5, {3}] | Repeated[6, {3}], Except[5 | 6]}]`?

Comment: It seems there is a slight ambiguity in my question; by "exactly three are $5$s or $6$s", I mean that exactly three of the dice show either $5$ or $6$. So `{5, 5, 6, 1}` is allowed, but not `{5, 5, 6, 6}`, for example. Can your (@J.M.) suggestion be modified to account for this? (Also is there a better way to phrase the requirement?)

Comment: `Cases[tuples, {Repeated[5 | 6, {3}], Except[5 | 6]}]`, then?

Comment: Yes! That works and confirms my result. Feel free to post that as an answer. I'll keep this question open to see what others might come up with :)

Comment: Does it have to be the last of the four that is the non-5/6?

Comment: Echoing @Daniel, *I'm trying to enumerate a sample space for an experiment in which 4 fair 6-sided dice are rolled such that exactly 3 of them are 5s or 6s. The way I understand it, the last die must be any number other than 5 or 6.* The way *I* understand it, *one of the dice* must be any number other than 5 or 6.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau You're right! Apologies! I've accidentally been treating this as a geometric experiment rather than a binomial one this entire time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question is: what is the probability of having exactly 3: 5/6 results with 4 throws of die:

```
p = BinomialDistribution[4, 1/3]
Probability[x == 3, x \[Distributed] p]
```

yields: 8/81

If the question is the probability of getting (5/6)(5/6)(5/6)(1234), regarding throwing 1,2,3 or 4 as success you can use[`GeometricDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricDistribution.html):

```
g = GeometricDistribution[2/3]
Probability[x == 3, x \[Distributed] g]
```

yields: 2/81

(as expected 1/4 of the preceding result given there are 4 ways to get exactly 3: 5/6 and one non 5/6)

Or simulation (as per @ciao):

```
Length[Tuples[{{5, 6}, {5, 6}, {5, 6}, Range[4]}]]/6^4
```

yields 2/81

Answer (score 5):

Also:

```
tuples = Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 4]; 
constrainedtuples = Tuples[{{5, 6}, {5, 6}, {5, 6}, Range[4]}];
Length[constrainedtuples]
```

> 32

```
Length[constrainedtuples]/Length[tuples]
```

> 2/81

Comment: FML - typed the "Why generate then filter, just generate" answer, *then* saw yours... +1

Comment: +1 for such a concise solution !!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a brute-force method. Starting from the sample space:

```
tuples = Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 4];
```

To enumerate the dice quadruples:

```
Cases[tuples, {Repeated[5 | 6, {3}], Except[5 | 6]}]
   {{5, 5, 5, 1}, {5, 5, 5, 2}, {5, 5, 5, 3}, {5, 5, 5, 4}, {5, 5, 6, 1}, {5, 5, 6, 2},
    {5, 5, 6, 3}, {5, 5, 6, 4}, {5, 6, 5, 1}, {5, 6, 5, 2}, {5, 6, 5, 3}, {5, 6, 5, 4},
    {5, 6, 6, 1}, {5, 6, 6, 2}, {5, 6, 6, 3}, {5, 6, 6, 4}, {6, 5, 5, 1}, {6, 5, 5, 2},
    {6, 5, 5, 3}, {6, 5, 5, 4}, {6, 5, 6, 1}, {6, 5, 6, 2}, {6, 5, 6, 3}, {6, 5, 6, 4},
    {6, 6, 5, 1}, {6, 6, 5, 2}, {6, 6, 5, 3}, {6, 6, 5, 4}, {6, 6, 6, 1}, {6, 6, 6, 2},
    {6, 6, 6, 3}, {6, 6, 6, 4}}
```

where the pattern `{Repeated[5 | 6, {3}], Except[5 | 6]}` imposes the restriction of the first three dice being either `5` or `6`. and the last die not being `5` or `6`.

To get the probability:

```
Count[tuples, {Repeated[5 | 6, {3}], Except[5 | 6]}]/Length[tuples]
   2/81
```

Comment: really nice pattern for `Count` :)

Answer (score 2):

probability is 8/81:

```
eventOccurs[L : {a_, b_, c_, d_}] := Count[L, 5] + Count[L, 6];
Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 4];
Count[Map[eventOccurs, %], 3]
probability = %/Length[%%]
```

Comment: I have two methods that agree 2/81 is the correct probability. Could you add an explanation for your approach?

Comment: I read too quickly; eventOccurs should be changed to prevent the last die from beiing 5 or 6:

Comment: Right. It looks like this counts e.g. `{5, 5, 5, 1}`, `{5, 5, 1, 5}`, `{5, 1, 5, 5}`, and `{1, 5, 5, 5}` as individual outcomes when they should be considered the same.

Comment: It is not obvious from the problem description why these should be regarded as the same. I could understand a scenario wherein they are different but the last three are disallowed outcomes.

Answer (score 2):

Probability is 2/81; I read too quickly! revised code changes the test:

```
eventOccurs[L : {a_, b_, c_, d_}] := 
    d < 5 && (Count[L, 5] + Count[L, 6]) == 3;
Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 4];
Count[Map[eventOccurs, %], True];
probability = %/Length[%%]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = (Permutations[Flatten@ConstantArray[Range@6, 4], {4}]);
Length@Select[list, And@@Thread[#[[1 ;; 3]] >= 5] && #[[4]] < 5 & ]/Length@list
(* 2/81 *)
```